# Is there any way to assign the col_types by column names in read_excel(readxl) in R

Tags: r, excel, readxl

My application is reading the `xls` and `xlsx` files using the `read_excel` function of the `readxl` package.

The sequence and the exact number of columns are not known earlier while reading the `xls` or `xlsx` file. There are **15 predefined columns** out of which **10 columns** are **mandatory** and remaining **5 columns** are **optional**. So the file will always have **minimum 10** columns and at **maximum 15** columns.

I need to specify the the `col-types` to the mandatory 10 columns. The only way I can think of is using the column names to specify the `col_types` as I know for fact that the file has all 10 columns which are mandatory but they are in the random sequence.

I tried looking out for the way of doing so but failed to do so.

Can anyone help me find a way to assign the col_types by column names?

Comment: The short answer is no; it's not like `reader::cols`. If the structure is very regular you might be able to fake it, but that doesn't sound like what you have. A simpler option is just to read in everything and subset. If types are causing problems, read everything as character and use `readr::type_convert` or `lapply` `type.convert` to clean up.

Comment: Yeah. I thought about that the option you have mentioned. I just wanted to avoid the overhead of type conversion post file reading. But as you said if there is no other option, I might need to go with it.

Comment: Honestly, with 15 variables the time type conversion takes will be negligible until your data is millions of rows.

Comment: @alistaire agree.

Comment: @alistaire As i don't know the exact number of columns, I won't be be able to specify the `col_types`. Any thoughts on it?

Comment: readr's `col_types` parameters can take a `cols` (or `cols_only` if you want to exclude excess variables) call, which can take column names attached to a specified parser. Otherwise, just stop worrying, read everything in, and clean it up after you've got it; trying to fix too much on import will take much more time than just fixing it after the fact with the typical `as.integer` and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem by below workaround. It is not the best way to solve this problem though. I have **read the excel file twice** which will take a hit on performance if the file has very large volume of data.

**First read:** **Building column data type vector**- Reading the file for retrieving the columns information(like column names, number of columns and it's types) and building the `column_data_types` `vector` which will have the `datatype` for every column in the file.

```
#reading .xlsx file
site_data_columns <- read_excel(paste(File$datapath, ".xlsx", sep = ""))

site_data_column_names <- colnames(site_data_columns)

for(i in 1 : length(site_data_column_names)){  

    #where date is a column name
    if(site_data_column_names[i] == "date"){
         column_data_types[i] <- "date"

         #where result is a column name
         } else if (site_data_column_names[i] == "result") {
                      column_data_types[i] <- "numeric"

         } else{
                column_data_types[i] <- "text"
        }
}
```

**Second read:** **Reading the file content-** reading the excel file by supplying `col_types` parameter with the `vector` `column_data_types` which has the column `data types`.

```
#reading .xlsx file
site_data <- read_excel(paste(File$datapath, ".xlsx", sep = ""), col_types = column_data_types)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extract all variable names and types from a .xlsx file you know it´s correct and save this in a vector, then use it for any other xlsx as reference:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# This is the reference dataset you know it`s correct:
ref_df <- readxl::read_xlsx("ref_df.xlsx"))
var_classes <- sapply(ref_df,class) %>% unlist

# This is the dataset you want to specify the column types:
target_df <- readxl::read_xlsx("target_df.xlsx"))

for (i in (var_classes %>% names)) {
 if(exists(i,target_df)) {
   class(target_df[[i]]) <- var_classes[i]
 }}
```

Please note this works no matter the order of the columns; it doesn´t matter if a variable is present in `ref_df` but does not exist in `target_df` either.

It just requires the variable exists in `ref_df` and it is called the same in `target_df`.